# IntelliJ PlugIn Development- Get the Project Structure

Tags: intellij-plugin, visitor-pattern, virtual-file

I want to visualize a part of the project structure. Therefore I need something like a VirtualFileVisitor that can be attached to a VirtualFile. (2 get the subtree of this element).
Does something like this exists? And are there some examples online?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualFileVisitor in com.intellij.openapi.vfs package. You can new it, and Override method depends on your business logic.